# Cannot prevent auto-commit in SQLite3 for Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am stumped in the behavior of python's builtin module sqlite3.
The following code prints out the data inserted regardless of if I comment out/in the line containing commit statement. How can that be?

My understanding from reading the python doc is that while sqlite3's underlying C library has autocommit enabled by default, the python binding does not. Instead, I have to add `isolation_level=None` to connect() call in order to enable auto-commit. I am asking this because I want to turn off auto-commit and could not find a way to do so.

My Python version is 3.9.2, and since sqlite3 is a builtin module, the module version is also 3.9.2 I think.

```
import sqlite3
import os

if os.path.exists("dummy.db"):
    os.system('rm dummy.db')
assert not os.path.exists("dummy.db") #ensure dummy.db is a new db every run

# Write
c = sqlite3.connect("dummy.db")
ddl = '''--sql
CREATE TABLE foo_table (foo INTEGER, bar INTEGER, foobar INTEGER);
'''
c.execute(ddl)

ddl = '''--sql
INSERT INTO foo_table VALUES(1,2,3); 
'''
c.execute(ddl)

#c.commit()
c.close()

# Read
c = sqlite3.connect("dummy.db")
ddl = 'SELECT * FROM foo_table'
for row in c.execute(ddl):
    print(row)
```

Output

```
>>(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands with "--sql" line in SQLite are run in a script mode which appears to be auto-commit by default as opposed to executing single SQL commands which uses manual commit mode by default for insert, update, delete, etc. If change the command from `--sql` to a standard SQL command then the insert is deferred until an expicit commit is executed.

```python
con = sqlite3.connect("dummy.db")
cursor = con.cursor()
# auto-commit mode for CREATE/ALTER/DROP
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE foo_table (foo INTEGER, bar INTEGER, foobar INTEGER)')
# Manual commit mode (the default) for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo_table VALUES(1,2,3)')
# uncomment commit below and the row will be inserted
#con.commit()
con.close()

# Read
con = sqlite3.connect("dummy.db")
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM foo_table')
result = cursor.fetchall()
print("rows=", len(result), sep='')
for row in result:
    print(row)
```

**Output:**

```
rows=0
```

If you want autocommit mode enabled for SQL commands, then set isolation_level to None.

```
con = sqlite3.connect("dummy.db", isolation_level=None)
```

**Output:**

```
rows=1
(1, 2, 3)
```

For more fine-grain control, you can use [transactions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), with BEGIN, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK commands. If call rollback or simply close the connection then insert is not committed.

```
cursor.execute("begin")
cursor.execute("INSERT...")
cursor.execute("rollback")
```

Comment: Thank you! Deleting the --sql worked like a charm. I am really surprised because the `--sql` was there for VS Code extension that highlights SQL syntax within .py file. I thought it had no effect on the code itself because `--` acted as a comment for SQL, letting it ignore whatever was behind it until line end. Why does the (non)existence  of `--sql` converts between ddl and sql command?

Comment: @ShuheiYamada - If call cursor.executescript('INSERT...') vs cursor.execute('INSERT..') then auto-commit is enabled so `--sql` in the SQL calling execute() must enable script mode which is auto-commit enabled.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I can put hours of head-scratching to rest. Python doc for sqlite3 mentions nothing of the `--` comment, it probably was not meant to be used.